# Openssl function not working correctly without return 0

Tags: c, function, encryption, openssl, return

I have encrypt/decrypt functions written in C. I encrypt a string and save it into a file. Later I read the file and decrypt the content. I am having a problem when doing the second operation in a separate function. Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/des.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

char *
Encrypt( char *Key, char *Msg, int size)
{

        static char*    Res;
        int             n=0;
        DES_cblock      Key2;
        DES_key_schedule schedule;

        Res = ( char * ) malloc( size );

        /* Prepare the key for use with DES_cfb64_encrypt */
        memcpy( Key2, Key,8);
        DES_set_odd_parity( &Key2 );
        DES_set_key_checked( &Key2, &schedule );

        /* Encryption occurs here */
        DES_cfb64_encrypt( ( unsigned char * ) Msg, ( unsigned char * ) Res,
                           size, &schedule, &Key2, &n, DES_ENCRYPT );

         return (Res);
}


char *
Decrypt( char *Key, char *Msg, int size)
{

        static char*    Res;
        int             n=0;

        DES_cblock      Key2;
        DES_key_schedule schedule;

        Res = ( char * ) malloc( size );

        /* Prepare the key for use with DES_cfb64_encrypt */
        memcpy( Key2, Key,8);
        DES_set_odd_parity( &Key2 );
        DES_set_key_checked( &Key2, &schedule );

        /* Decryption occurs here */
        DES_cfb64_encrypt( ( unsigned char * ) Msg, ( unsigned char * ) Res,
                           size, &schedule, &Key2, &n, DES_DECRYPT );

        return (Res);

}

void test()
{
    char key[]="1234";
//    
    char writeBuffer[4096];
    char *decrypted;
//    char *encrypted;
//    
//    encrypted=malloc(sizeof(writeBuffer));
    decrypted=malloc(sizeof(writeBuffer));

    int fp1 = open("encrypted.txt", O_RDONLY);
    int bytes_read = 0;
    bytes_read = read(fp1, writeBuffer, sizeof(writeBuffer)-1);

    memcpy(decrypted,Decrypt(key,writeBuffer,sizeof(writeBuffer)), sizeof(writeBuffer));
    printf("Decrypted text\t : %s \n",decrypted);

}


int main() {


    char key[]="1234";

    char writeBuffer[4096];
    char *decrypted;
    char *encrypted;

    encrypted=malloc(sizeof(writeBuffer));
    decrypted=malloc(sizeof(writeBuffer));

    char clear[]="This is a secret message";


    printf("Clear text\t : %s \n",clear);
    memcpy(encrypted,Encrypt(key,clear,sizeof(writeBuffer)), sizeof(writeBuffer));
    printf("Encrypted text\t : %s \n",encrypted);
    FILE *f = fopen("encrypted.txt", "w");
    fwrite(encrypted, sizeof(writeBuffer), 1, f);
    fclose(f);

    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i < 2; i++){

// Uncommenting the section below and commenting test() works properly 

//    int fp1 = open("encrypted.txt", O_RDONLY);
//    int bytes_read = 0;
//    bytes_read = read(fp1, writeBuffer, sizeof(writeBuffer)-1);
//    
//    memcpy(decrypted,Decrypt(key,writeBuffer,sizeof(writeBuffer)), sizeof(writeBuffer));
//    printf("Decrypted text\t : %s \n",decrypted);
        test();
    }

 //       close(fp1);
    return (0);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line, you are reading one byte less than you are writing to the file:

```
bytes_read = read(fp1, writeBuffer, sizeof(writeBuffer)-1);
```

I tested your code without the -1 and it works.

Furthermore, your code has several problems, your function should take `const` parameters, some memory gets allocated and is never freed. Some code could be better written, for example:

```
int bytes_read = 0;
bytes_read = read(fp1, writeBuffer, sizeof(writeBuffer)-1);
```

should be:

```
int bytes_read = read(fp1, writeBuffer, sizeof(writeBuffer)-1);
```

The code is also not consistent, you use once `fopen` and `FILE` which are in the standard C library, and once `open` and a file descriptor which are part of POSIX.

Edit:
Here is your modified code I tested (you must compile it with C99 activated, "-std=c99"):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/des.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

char *
Encrypt(const char *Key, const char *Msg, int size)
{
    /* Prepare the key for use with DES_cfb64_encrypt */
    DES_cblock Key2;
    memcpy( Key2, Key, 8);
    DES_set_odd_parity( &Key2 );
    DES_key_schedule schedule;
    DES_set_key_checked( &Key2, &schedule );

    /* Encryption occurs here */
    int n = 0;
    char *Res = malloc( size );
    DES_cfb64_encrypt( ( unsigned char * ) Msg, ( unsigned char * ) Res,
            size, &schedule, &Key2, &n, DES_ENCRYPT );
    return Res;
}

char *
Decrypt(const char *Key, const char *Msg, int size)
{
    /* Prepare the key for use with DES_cfb64_encrypt */
    DES_cblock      Key2;
    memcpy( Key2, Key,8);
    DES_set_odd_parity( &Key2 );
    DES_key_schedule schedule;
    DES_set_key_checked( &Key2, &schedule );

    /* Decryption occurs here */
    int n = 0;
    char *Res = malloc( size );
    DES_cfb64_encrypt( ( unsigned char * ) Msg, ( unsigned char * ) Res,
            size, &schedule, &Key2, &n, DES_DECRYPT );
    return (Res);
}

void test()
{
    char key[] = "12345678";
    char writeBuffer[4096];
    char *decrypted = malloc(sizeof(writeBuffer));

    int fp1 = open("encrypted.txt", O_RDONLY);
    int bytes_read = read(fp1, writeBuffer, sizeof(writeBuffer));

    memcpy(decrypted,
        Decrypt(key,writeBuffer,sizeof(writeBuffer)),
        sizeof(writeBuffer));
    printf("Decrypted text\t : %s \n",decrypted);

}


int main() {
    char key[]="12345678";
    char writeBuffer[4096];

    char clear[] = "This is a secret message";
    printf("Clear text\t : %s \n",clear);

    char *encrypted = malloc(sizeof(writeBuffer));
    memcpy(encrypted, Encrypt(key, clear, sizeof(writeBuffer)), sizeof(writeBuffer));
    printf("Encrypted text\t : %s \n",encrypted);

    FILE *f = fopen("encrypted.txt", "w");
    fwrite(encrypted, sizeof(writeBuffer), 1, f);
    fclose(f);

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        // Uncommenting the section below and commenting test() works properly 
        if (0) {
            int fp1 = open("encrypted.txt", O_RDONLY);
            int bytes_read = read(fp1, writeBuffer, sizeof(writeBuffer));

            char *decrypted = malloc(sizeof(writeBuffer));
            memcpy(decrypted, 
                    Decrypt(key, writeBuffer, sizeof(writeBuffer)),
                    sizeof(writeBuffer));
            printf("Decrypted text\t : %s \n",decrypted);
            close(fp1);
        }
        else {
            test();
        }
    }

    return (0);

}
```

Comment: Thanks Etienne. I removed the -1, however the problem still remains...in which environment did you test? I am testing OS X.

Comment: I tested in Debian, I edited my answer with the code I used, can you test it?

Comment: Part of your problem is that in `test` has `key` defined as `char key[] = "1234"` which is 5 bytes, and in `Decrypt`, it does a     `memcpy(key2, key, 8)`, which explains why `test` is not correctly decrypting.

Comment: Etienne, I tried the code as it is. On OSX it fails, but on an Ubuntu machine it works! any idea why?

Comment: TonyB, using an 8 byte key fixed the issue. Thanks!